# makefile: variable evaluation in function call?

Tags: makefile

Say I have a makefile like this:

```
DIRS=foo bar
```

I'd like to enumerate files in subdirectories of these directories, so I can pass all of them at once to a program. This isn't working:

```
UNIT_FILES=()
find_units:
    for c in $(DIRS); do UNIT_FILES+=($(wildcard $(c)/systemd/*)); done
```

However, this works:

```
UNIT_FILES=()
find_units:
    UNIT_FILES+=($(wildcard foo/systemd/*))
```

So I know the issue is with my variable evaluation in the call to `wildcard`. I've tried variations on this, including `$(c)`, `$$c` and the like, but I'm just taking stabs in the dark here.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can't test right away if it works, but try using `$(foreach)` instead : `UNIT_FILES += $(foreach DIR, $(DIRS), $(wildcard $(DIR)/systemd/*))`.

Comment: @Chnossos that's great! Works like a charm. Post as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: Another option is `UNIT_FILES := $(wildcard $(DIRS:%=%/systemd/*))`.  Note you should always use `:=`, not `=`, with functions like this for efficiency.

Comment: @MadScientist What if UNIT_FILES already contains something ?

Comment: Then you can use `UNIT_FILES := $(UNIT_FILES) $(wildcard ...)`.  Or there are other alternatives (set some other variable to the results of the wildcard with `:=`, then append that to `UNIT_FILES`, etc.)  However in the examples given here that wasn't the case (I don't know why he's setting it to empty parens...)  If you use normal recursive expansion, the wildcard will be re-run every time you expand `UNIT_FILES` which is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :

```
for c in $(DIRS); do UNIT_FILES+=($(wildcard $(c)/systemd/*)); done
```

You're using a shell for-loop that will be called like this by make :

```
$(SHELL) -c "for c in $(DIRS); do UNIT_FILES+=($(wildcard $(c)/systemd/*)); done"
```

Nothing is actually expanded into UNIT_FILES because this command is not executed in the Makefile level.

You can achieve what you want with make builtin function `foreach` :

```
UNIT_FILES += $(foreach DIR, $(DIRS), $(wildcard $(DIR)/systemd/*))
```

Which is expanded into :

```
UNIT_FILES += $(wildcard foo/systemd/*) $(wildcard bar/systemd/*)
```